# Instability Hilbert Matrix unit vector

Tags: numpy, matrix, scipy, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Let `H(n)`  be a Hilbert matrix of order `n`.

Let `e = (0,...,0,1)` - unit vector.

Let `e_im := H(n) * e`.

I solve `H(n) * x_1 = e_im` by using some computer algebra system.

Let `r = (r_1,...,r_n)` be small random vector.

Let `(e + r)_im := H(n) * (e + r)`.

I solve `H(n) * x_2 = (e + r)_im` by using some computer algebra system.

Why is residial `|| H(n) * x_1 - e_im ||` so small, but `|| H(n) * x_2 - (e + r)_im||` so very big?

I use numpy and scipy.linalg, my code:

```
H = scipy.linalg.hilbert(500)

e = numpy.zeros((500, 1))

e[499] = 1

e_im = H.dot(e)

x_1 = scipy.linalg.solve(H, e_im)

r = 0.0001 * numpy.random.rand(500, 1)

e_plusr_im = e + r

x_2 = scipy.linalg.solve(H, e_plusr_im)

Residials = [scipy.linalg.norm(H.dot(x_1) - b_1, 2), scipy.linalg.norm(H.dot(x_2) - b_2, 2)]
```

Comment: You should show some code in order to help. It may depends on type of algorithm used.

Comment: @Warren Weckesser, yes

Answer (score 3):

This is well-known numerical linear algebra phenomenon, (cf. most linear algebra course materials).

The [condition number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) `kappa(A) = ||A|| ||A^-1||` of a matrix tells how much matrix inversion amplifies errors in the generic case. Here:

```
>>> import scipy.linalg
>>> import numpy as np
>>> H = scipy.linalg.hilbert(500)
>>> np.linalg.cond(H)
4.6335026663215786e+20
```

As a rule of thumb, the (deterministic) floating point error has relative magnitude 1e-16 for 64-bit floats. The condition number is so big that the resulting error has relative magnitude > 1, so you can lose all precision from that alone unless you get lucky and the solution and intermediate calculations have exact floating point representations. If you manually add noise, it will also be amplified.